# How to write content on another site with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need some kind of technology/tool in order to write content on another website.
I know that Ajax alows me to retrive content, but wont work for me.
The technology/tool needs to access the url, type the login/passoword, get the response, and then input some text and click one button.
Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just a JavaScript framework, which doesn't bring anything special itself. The things which you are talking about - are regular HTTP requests, done via AJAX through JS.

Your purpose is not clearly defined in the question.

In case you need to emulate customers behavior - you may use tools alike QA-dudes use for web browser automation, alike [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

It seems you don't really understand what is jQuery, Ajax, HTTP-auth, and other terms, so you chosen the wrong direction of investigation. Use ready made tools, without programming. Or if you know the deal - then such questions wouldn't pop-up here.

You may start your investigation from understanding how HTTP works, what is `POST` and what is `GET` HTTP request, how to make them via `curl`, what is `AJAX`, etc.

Comment: ok, I have a VBA macro that does the actions I need. But some user on my job dont have Excel, and cant install others browsers and addons. Thats why I wanted to have my solution with jQuery.

Comment: @thiago, it's strange way of using VBA and jQuery, but probably you understand why you choose these tools. You may try to [convert your VBA macro to VBScript](http://analystcave.com/excel-running-excel-macro-vbscript-cmd/), which is natively supported on Windows